# Хэширование WordPress

Tags: wordpress, хеширование, пароль

При регистрации в wp сейчас используется "wp hash password", а мне нужно чтобы было md5, как по старинке.

Как это реализовать?

p.s: Версия вп последняя

Comment: Ребят, если в этом русле нет вариантов, то как можно реализовать отправку пароля в два столбца
То есть будет допустим password(это хэширование от wp) и passwordmd5(это уже дополнительный столбец)

Comment: ВП ХРАНИТ не в md5,  но прекрасно его понимает. При логине изменит хеш. См подробности https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/перенос-пользователей-с-паролями-с-др

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше этого не делать. md5 давным-давно признан небезопасным и устаревшим. Но если сильно хочется, то то можно. Функция `wp_hash_password()` является подключаемой (pluggable) и может быть заменена своей.

Создайте файл плагина `wp-content/plugins/test-pluggable/test-pluggable.php` и добавьте в него такой код:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: MD5 as Password Hash
 * Plugin URI:
 * Description: Test plugin to use MD5 as Password Hash
 * Author: KAGG Design
 * Version: 0.0.1
 * Author URI: https://kagg.eu/en/
 * Requires at least: 1.5.1
 * Tested up to: 5.0
 *
 * Text Domain: pwd-hash
 * Domain Path: /languages/
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

/**
 * Create a hash (encrypt) of a plain text password.
 *
 * @param string $password Plain text user password to hash
 *
 * @return string The hash string of the password
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_hash_password' ) ) {
    function wp_hash_password( $password ) {

        return md5( trim( $password ) );
    }
}
```

Активируйте плагин.